# Make a list of xs:enumeration appear in <menuChoices/> XML element without repeating them

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, enumeration

In my schema, I have a `colorName` enum list, a `<color name="one_of_colorName"/>` element, and a `<colorsUsed/>` element with a unique list of `<color/>`s used, thus:

```
<!-- color name list -->
<xs:simpleType name="colorName">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="green" />  <!-- etc. -->
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- color element, just go with the col: namespace -->
<xs:element name="color">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="col:colorName" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- unique list of colors used -->
<xs:element name="colorsUsed">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- let's hold off on max which must be the length of the color name list -->
      <xs:element ref="col:color" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- enforce unique color name in the list -->
  <xs:unique name="uniqueColorName">
    <xs:selector xpath="col:color"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

Question 1: I would like to have the `<colorChoices/>` menu populated with all the colors in the color name list, *without repeating them, either in the schema or the XML file*, along these lines:

```
<xs:element name="colorChoices">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>                         <!-- need the name list, one each -->
      <xs:element ref="col:color"/>  <!-- ?? what how ?? -->
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Question 2: I have a working solution, but would be nice to have: In `<colorsUsed/>` element, can I restrict `maxOccurs=length_of_colorName_list`?

Thanks for the answer or the link to an existing answer, which I can't seem to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List all `<color>` choices whose type is `xs:string`, in the menu element `<colorChoices/>` and get rid of the enum list. Then enforce uniqueness of `<color name="???"/>` in both `<colorChoices/>` and `<colorsUsed/>`. If you know of a better answer, please update. Thanks.